# Postgres trigger only insert if different than last inserted value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I'm using an external api to make daily requests and ask about a products charateristics daily. I get price, quantity, description. This set of attributes i log in a Postgres table, for each request:

```
product_data (id, productId, productQty, productDescr);
```

The price and quantity modify daily, so i need to insert them in the DB always, but the description modifies once every few weekes so I would only want to insert if it's different than the last logged description.
For this i was thinking to create a trigger that would when inserting a description, would check if it's different than the last inserted description for that productId, and if it's not, just insert null. if it's different insert the new description.

Is this possible? Can someone provide some hints on how proceed in developing such trigger?

Comment: Please read [PostgreSQL trigger function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

In triggers you will have access to the current record and the new data through OLD and NEW, so in your trigger you should be able to decide what to insert using something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) 
VALUES 
(CASE WHEN OLD.description<>NEW.description THEN new.description ELSE NULL END);
```

But then you can nolonger detect when the description is actually removed, either on purpose or by a bug; the NULL can be a result of an unchanging value, or an actual NULL value.

Comment: It's probably better to use `OLD.description IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.description` to cater for NULL values.

Comment: A NULL will be stored if there is no difference or if the new value really is a NULL. You can't tell which has happpend by looking at the stored NULL value.